# Как принять и записать в базу данных чекбоксы из формы?

Tags: laravel

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как принять и записать теги из чекбоксов в бд. Сейчас до контроллера доходит только один тег.

```js
public
function add() {
  $tags = Tag::all();
  $categories = Category::all();
  return view('addPost', compact('tags', 'categories'));
}

public
function create(Request $request) {

  $this - > validate($request, [
    'title' => 'required',
  ]);
  $post = new Post();
  $post - > title = $request - > title;
  $post - > category = $request - > category;
  $post - > content = $request - > content;
  $post - > tags = $request - > tags;
  $post - > creator = Auth::user() - > name;
  $post - > save();
  return dd($request);
}
}
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="/addpost">

  <div class="form-group">
    <p><input type="text" name="title"></p>
    <p> <textarea name="content" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea> </p>
    <p>
      <select name="category">
        @foreach($categories as $category)
        <option value="{{ $category->title }}">{{ $category->title }}</option>
        @endforeach
      </select>
    </p>
    <p>
      <h3>Tags</h3>
    </p>
    @foreach($tags as $tag)
    <p><input type="checkbox" name="tags" value="{{ $tag->title }}">{{ $tag->title }}</p>
    @endforeach
    <button type="submit">Add post</button>
  </div>


  {{ csrf_field() }}
</form>
```

Comment: В атрибуте `name` должно быть `name="tags[]"`

Comment: А как принять массив в контроллере?

Comment: Можете попробовать `$post->tags()->sync($request->tags)`. Подробнее о [Syncing Associations](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#syncing-associations)

Comment: Мне выдает ошибку: BadMethodCallException
Call to undefined method App\Models\Post::tags()

Comment: А как вообще у Вас выглядит модель Post? У Вас же там должен быть обозначен релейшн с тегами, я конечно не настаиваю, но по идее должен быть Many To Many (Polymorphic) и в методе tags должно быть что-то вроде `public function tags(){ return $this->morphToMany(Tag::class, 'taggable'); }`. Самый наглядный пример с теми же тегами есть в [документации](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations)